# How know when a winform is loaded by Process.Start?

Tags: c#, winforms, process, loaded

I'm in a WindowsForm (c# .net 3.5) and on click of a button launch another external application (also .net 3.5) using Process.Start() and understand when it is available after i have launched it.

```
    ProcessStartInfo psInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"MyApplication.exe");
psInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
psInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
psInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
Process proc = Process.Start(psInfo);

proc... IsFullyLoaded()?
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To wait for the process to create its form, call the [`WaitForInputIdle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforinputidle.aspx) method.

To find out whether it's ready, try this:

```
bool isReady = proc.WaitForInputIdle(0);
```

Or, alternatively,

```
bool isReady = (proc.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero);
```

You can also use the MainWindowHandle property to send messages to the form using the [`SendMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28VS.85%29.aspx) API function

Answer (score 0):

You could pass an argument to the process letting it know how it was launched.

```
psInfo.Arguments = "-startedByProcess";
```

Then have the child process callback to the owner process to let it know it has started, via remoting or something like that.