# c# .net4 application launched from network drive takes long time to load

Tags: c#, .net, networking, splash-screen, drive

Let me better explain my scenario. I would like to launch the .exe from a network drive. I have noticed that a small .net 4 form with 1 component (progress bar) takes about 20mb of memory if you check in the Win XP task manager. Hence, once the splash form is loaded it is taking about 20mb of memory in the taskbar.

So if the .exe is launched from a network drive the client machine has to wait until it has loaded the entire form into memory and then it show up. Which is taking about 2-3 minutes. So it has to wait for the 20mb to load. What would be the best method to display a splash screen immediately when launching the .exe from a network drive? Say instead of waiting for the 20MB to fully download, is it possible to display the splash screen when only less than 1mb has been downloaded into the client memory? Could you provide suggestions on how to do this?

I have checked this out by looking at the task manager on the client machine and until the .exe reaches about 20 MB then the splash form is displayed. Then it waits until the .exe reaches about 40MB to display the main form. I would like the splash to display in less than two seconds from when the exe is launched from the network drive so the user knows the exe will finish loading in about 2-3 minutes. So how to achieve this?

By the way, it takes a long time to load because the client machines reside off site and there is a VPN that connects the machines to the central file server. That is why the loading is taking a while because the upload link is at most 1Mb. But once the .exe has finished loading there is no slowness. The best way would be to have terminal services or citrix. But this is not an option for now. Or install each .exe at the client machine but i would prefer not to go down that path.

Comment: That's not how it works.  But that's not the point, 1Mb is atrocious.  Make a local copy and be done with it.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at ClickOnce deployment. Potentially, it will allow you to keep your single network copy for ease of deployment, but will save the clients from downloading the application unless it's been updated.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d

Answer (score 0):

You might consider building a second application that does nothing but:

1. display the splash screen
2. launch a new Windows Process pointing to the remote exe.

-

I think this question contains an approximation of the code you would need:

[How know when a winform is loaded by Process.Start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177956/how-know-when-a-winform-is-loaded-by-process-start)

Comment: Yes that will work if the second application resides on the client machines. But this will mean installing the launcher application on all the client machines and there are a lot. Is there another way to avoid doing this? Preferably somehow to be able to "Force" the splash screen to display immediately when the .exe is launched from the network drive and less than 1MB has been loaded into the client's machine? Not sure if this is even possible.

Comment: actually you can do this by having the 2 executables in the networked folder so you don't need to install anything on the clients still. The first tiny exe can load the second one in the same folder (the networked one)

Comment: Having 2 executables will work, but it should be possible to do this with a single executable using multiple assemblies instead.

Answer (score 0):

The memory use in the task manager process tab is local only and is not downloaded from the networked computer! When you load an application from a network drive it downloads the executable only and executes it locally; this is how every OS has always done it, it is NOT executed on the server and streamed.

I have a newsletter sending application here for example, 15kb exe, 4.3mb in ram use when loaded (large lists of data so that's expected)

Loaded from a server in the USA via VPN to my local machine (i'm in Australia on a ADSL 1,512 link... so ULTRA slow!) it loads the application in ~1-2 second(s) and there is no way i can download 4.3mb in 1 second... i wish :)

So what can you do about your problem?

If the executable is huge and packed with embedded resources (images, videos, list's, XML etc)... you can make them external files instead and show a loading window for the user, perhaps cache files locally too so it only needs to be done once and launching the application is then quick. Changes to resources can be checked and re-downloaded via the application

If the application executable is small and there are no external files/resources being accessed either (in the networked folder or online) then you simply have some network problems to manage :)

Answer (score 0):

The .Net runtime only loads assemblies as they are needed - if you keep your executable as small as possible (just the bare minimun required to display a splash screen) and put the rest of your code into a larger assemply then in theory your splash screen can be shown very quickly before the larger assembly needs to be loaded.

The key to achieving this is understanding when the .Net framework will attempt to load an assembly - more precisely it will load an assembly just before it begins executing any method that references a type contained in that assembly.  Try experimenting with the following program to understand this better:

```
// Contained in FirstAssembly.exe
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        PrintLoadedAssemblies("start of Main");
        innerMain();
    }

    static void innerMain()
    {
        PrintLoadedAssemblies("start of innerMain");
        OtherClass obj;
    }

    static void PrintLoadedAssemblies(string point)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Loaded assemblies at {0}", point);
        foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(assembly.FullName);
        }
    }
}

// Contained in OtherAssembly.dll
class OtherClass
{

}
```

Armed with this knowledge we now know that in order to get our splash screen to display before loading the second larger assembly we need to make sure that our splash screen is shown before we execute any method that references any type in our larger assembly - its difficult for me to test this, but if we have a fairly standard splash screen:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.Run(new SplashScreen());
}
```

Then the first point that we should reference any types in the larger assembly should be in something like the `SplashScreen_Shown` event, something like:

```
void SplashScreen_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (new MainForm()).Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Also note that this will happen on the main / UI thread and so your splash screen is unresponsive while the larger assembly is being loaded - if this is unacceptable then you need to refactor the above so that the method containing the `MainForm` reference is in an asynchronous thread.

Answer (score -2):

Hey thanks for your answers. After your suggestions i have thought about the following solution. A have built a console application that when you launch it from the network drive, it launches very quick. In under two seconds. This console application will be my splash screen, not pretty but at least the user will know that something is happening. The console exe will launch the .exe i want to really load and at least the user will know that its loading and will take several minutes to load. If possible the console application will display how much time is left. I just gotta now figure out how to do this using a console application. Once the main .exe has loaded I then have to close the console application.

Any one know how to do this from a console application?